# Casting string to Web Control and targeting variable in container

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

Using VWD 2010 C#. Default.aspx(.cs).
Whats to happen: A button changes the color of a label with `ID = "Day31"`.
Given that it is the 31st day of the month for this example.
The button and label are positioned inside a table inside "MainContent".

```
protected void Red_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as   ContentPlaceHolder;
    int theday;
    theday = System.DateTime.Now.Day; // example the day is 31st
    string str="Day"+theday;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + str+ "');", true);
    Label dayLabel = FindControl(str) as Label;

    dayLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; // this line error, "Null"
}
```

Question: Why is there a `Null` error message at this line of code?

Comment: Try `MainContent.FindControl` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's null either because there is no control with that particular ID value in the container that the method is in, or the control that has that ID value isn't a `Label`, it's some other type.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `Label dayLabel = MainContent.FindControl(str) as Label;` it should work.